# Difficulty running regetron in cmd

Tags: python, regex

I want to follow the regex tutorial on http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-regex-the-hard-waych1.html, but I am unsure how to execute regetron in cmd. I have followed the instructions to install it and the python interpreter does not give me an error when I type import regetron, so I know for certain it is installed.

Comment: I reccommend just using http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ Its good for working with regex ... its not python but it helps your regex

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but FWIW, I've found [Kodos - The Python Regular Expression Debugger](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/home.html) very useful for experimenting with regexes.

Answer (score 5):

Scripts usually get installed into the Scripts folder of your Python installation under Windows.  Assuming you have Python 2.7 installed in the typical location, you should find a regetron executable in `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

FWIW, I typically put both `C:\Python27` and `C:\Python27\Scripts` on my path under Windows for the above reason.  Then commands introduced by packages are immediately available on the command line.

**UPDATE**: Regetron doesn't currently work for Windows.  I've proposed a couple of patches to make it work.  In the meantime, you can grab a new .zip [from here](http://www.szakmeister.net/downloads/regetron-1.4-windows.zip) and use pip to install it:

```
pip install .\regetron-1.4-windows.zip
```

**UPDATE**: My fixes have been incorporated into regetron.  It should now work fine under Windows in a future version of regetron.

Comment: I forgot to share that C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts are already environment variables.

Comment: Do you see `regetron` in `C:\Python27\Scripts`?

Comment: yeah i just tried it and it doesnt work ... renaming it to .py halfway fixes it ... but then come the import errors...

Comment: I was just looking at his Zed's site and the source.  Zed says it's broken on Windows right now. :-(

Comment: Instead of just adding a `.py` to the end, try adding `-cmd.py`.  That way it doesn't collide with the `regetron` package that it installs.  You would then run `regetron-cmd.py` from the command line instead.  Looking at the code, there's no reason that it can't run in Windows... it's just not been packaged well. :-(

Comment: Did you delete the `.pyc` files in the `Scripts` folder?  If not, then Python is picking up the byte-compiled version left over before you added the `-cmd` in the name.

Comment: @jszakmeister It is definitely in there also there is no .pyc file in scripts for regetron

Comment: Upon calling regetron-cmd.py in the Scripts directory, I was given an error that says
No readline support, so no scroll back for you.
Traceback <most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\regetron-cmd.py", line 22, in <module>
    SHELL.setup_readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\regetron\engine.py", line 34, in setup_rea
dline
    readline.read_history_file(histfile)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'readline' referenced before assignment

Comment: Bah.  That's a bug in regetron.  This is getting annoying... I'm going to fix it soon.

Comment: See my updated post.  You'll probably want to run `pip uninstall regetron` first.

Comment: PIP installs the old version of Regetron without this fix? Because I had the exact same issue (March 30, 2015) and the link posted above fixed it!

Comment: Yeah, it appears that while Zed pulled in the fix, another release was never made. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I used Cygwin to run regetron, and I did the following:

1. Install Cygwin, or update it if you already have it installed
2. Install Python when you pick your packages to install. Install wget,
   too, because it'll make one of the steps below easier
3. `wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py`
4. `python distribute_setup.py`
5. Use easy_install to install PIP. PIP is actively maintained, and supports package removal (unlike easy_install): `easy_install pip`
6. `pip install regetron`
7. Run regetron: `regetron`

Another word of caution: cmd.exe handles single-quoted (`'`)and double-quoted strings (`"`) differently than *nix shells. I've been burned when I've run Python scripts that take regex arguments (e.g. `pywikipediabot`) in cmd.exe. You can follow examples exactly, and the Wrong Thing will happen.

Cygwin doesn't have problems with `'` and `"`.